# Ionic 4 page dimensions after orientation change

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a component in my Ionic app, that requires the screen dimensions.  I am trying to use the `Platform` plugin to grab the new screen dimensions, after the user changes the orientation of their device.  I am trying to do so with the following code:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss'],
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  deviceWidth: number;
  deviceHeight: number;
  subs = new Subscription();

  constructor(private platform: Platform) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    subs.add(this.platform.resize.subscribe(async () => {
      this.deviceWidth = this.platform.width();
      this.deviceHeight = this.platform.height();
      console.log(this.platformHeight, this.platformWidth);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subs.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

The issue that I am running into is that `platform.resize` is called before the animation/transition to the new orientation is complete.  And thus, `platform.height()` and `platform.width()` are incorrect (they both get set to the smallest dimension of the device).  In order to test this, I tried the following for my resize subscription:

```js
    subs.add(this.platform.resize.subscribe(async () => {
      console.log(`Initial Call- width: ${this.platform.width}, height: ${this.platform.height}`);
      setTimeout({ // wait until long after the transition animation
        console.log(`After Transition- width: ${this.platform.width}, height: ${this.platform.height}`);
      }, 1000);
    });
```

which yields the following, after an orientation change from landscape to portrait:

```
Initial Call- width: 414, height: 414
After Transition- width: 414, height: 896
```

Any thoughts on how I can get the proper width/height, without inserting some random `setTimeout` in the subscription?

Comment: try to check isResize condition with boolean value?

Answer (score 0):

The best way i found for my app was to use screen orientation (https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/screen-orientation/).
With that framework you can check landscape/portrait orientation.

Then in your case you just have to make a promise inside the two IF you'll make to get proper size in each orientation